# Custom domains for customers via CNAME record?

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

I have a small SaaS app. It partially collects data through a service hosted at a subdomain, `beacon.example.com`.

I am trying to let my users create a custom domain to brand this address to `beacon.client-domain.com`.

I have tried CNAME records pointing `beacon.client-domain.com` ->  `beacon.example.com` but I am having issues with my lets encrypt certificates.

Is there a best practice way to accomplish this programmatically? Sorry for my ignorance in the land of DNS

Further info on the problem:
Lets encrypt setup works fine on the master `beacon.example.com` domain but when pointing the CNAME from the other domain to it I get the (understandable) "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" error in chrome due to the client domain not being in the cert.

**This question is simply asking what is the best practice already in industry to deal with such a situation where custom domain branding is required on a programmatic basis.**

Comment: "I am having issues with my lets encrypt certificates." What issues? Can't you merely set the CN to beacon.example.com?

Comment: 1) Give the true names involved if you want relevant help and answers, and otherwise for obfuscation use RFC2606 2) At least post specific command/tools you use and specific errors and responses you get

Comment: @MarkWagner LE setup works fine on the master `beacon.example.com` domain but when pointing the CNAME from the other domain to it I get the (understandable) "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" error in chrome due to the client domain not being in the cert. Thanks for your help

Comment: Best practice is to use a certificate that is valid for the domain it's being used for.

Comment: Why don't you just run Let's Encrypt for the other domain name, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Guess that is what I will have to do, in an automated fashion

Comment: LE supports SANs so you need only one cert with both beacon.client-domain.com and  beacon.example.com. You could probably take your current LE config and merely add beacon.client-domain.com as a SAN.

Comment: CloudFlare has released [CloudFlare for SaaS](https://www.cloudflare.com/saas/) which provides just that. It's available with their free tiers. Price is 100 custom domains for free, then $0.10/month per additional custom domain. Definitely a no-brainer coming from such a trusted brand.